# Jquery show/hide menu based on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've got a full screen cover image on a web page and when user scrolls down from the cover to the content, a floating menu will fade in. I got this part covered with the code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){                       

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('#scroll-down').offset().top) { 
           $('.menu').animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
           } 

});
```

What I can't get working, is to fade the menu out at same point if user scrolls back to the cover on the top. If I add 'else' condition animating opacity back to 0, the menu won't show up at all.

Comment: Please show your jsfiddle.

Comment: Let me try rephrase and simplify. If user has scrolled MORE that a viewport height - menu visible. If user has scrolled LESS than a viewport height - menu hidden.

Comment: @teeraina *If I add 'else' condition animating opacity back to 0, the menu won't show up at all*. Isn't that what you want, to hide menu? Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/p8bdt9t6/1/) it works well when it goes into *else*.

Comment: Try this 

     `$(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 0.3) {
                /code here
            }
        });` This is call when user is scrolled 30 percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these modifications. The key is to stop() the previous animation, before starting a new one. And also to set the fade-out location 10 pixels above the fade-in point.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){                       
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('#scroll-down').offset().top) { 
           $('.menu').stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
    } else if($(this).scrollTop() < $('#scroll-down').offset().top -10) {
           $('.menu').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Works well. You got it, even I failed to explain the #scroll-down element.